# How to find the all the temp file from all the app and show in list

Tags: android, listview, temporary-files

I am trying to **find out the list of temp file of all the app in one list**, but cant find any solution. 
so, please any one have any idea about

> "how to fetch list of temp file"

,

then please give me suggestion.
I am fresher in android and need a help.